# import a function to use the scope it is called from

Tags: meteor

Using Meteor, I am trying to use a function from one file on a template's scope lays in a different file. I tried using an arrow function:

first file:

```
export const myFunc = ()=>{
    console.log(this.x);
};
```

second file:

```
import {myFunc} from './myFunc.js';

Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function(){
    this.x = 4;
    myFunc(); //undefined
});
```

what is the best way of affecting template's variables using functions that aren't defined at the template itself? (I need those functions for some other templates as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about passing your template's variables as parameters to the function?
Combining that with the use of ReactiveVar you can set them in myFunc

```
import { myFund } from './myFunc.js'

Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  this.myVar = new ReactiveVar('Foo');
});

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  myFunc(this.myVar);
  console.log(this.myVar.get())  // 'Bar'
});
```

and in your function file

```
export const myFunc = (myVar) => {
  //Use myVar
  myVar.set('Bar')
};
```

Comment: i was trying to avoid doing that since there were so many variables to pass as parameters including primitives that aren't passed by reference, but ended up choosing that way and working around the problems in the end.